# PHP removing img after loaded

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have the following code:

```
<?php
    $dir_handle = 'assets/splashs/';
    foreach(array_diff(scandir($dir_handle), array('.', '..')) as $file) {
        echo '<img id="preload_header" src="assets/splashs/' . $file . '" /><br />';
    }
?>
```

I wondered if it were possible to check if the image is successfully loaded, if so then remove the image and move onto the next?

*My splashs folder has over 600 images in it, I don't want 600 images just sitting around on the side, but i'd like them to be preloaded for when I call them elsewhere.*

```
load image => successfully loaded => remove and onto next image
           => unsuccessfully loaded => remove image and stop
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: You can delete files using `unlink($filename);`

Comment: Are you trying to delete the image? If so, have a look at unlink function.

Comment: @JamesElliott - I'd like to remove the `<img>` tag once it has finished loading

Comment: @user3352340 what has this to do with PHP ?

Comment: You have to use js for this.

Comment: @DanFromGermany - I'd hope to keep it within the `foreach()`.. which is php

Comment: @user3352340 PHP is a backend only language. You'd have to do this with Javascript or some other frontend language.

Comment: @JamesElliott Okay, damn. Will do

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery/Javascript to replace broken images](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92720/jquery-javascript-to-replace-broken-images)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you preload images:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (document.images) {
    img1 = new Image();
    img1.src = "image.jpg";
}
</script>
```

So you don't load AND SHOW the image (`<img src="....">`) but you load them into the browser using JavaScript so you don't have to "remove the images" afterwards because they'll never get shown.

Can be combined ofc with foreach:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (document.images) {
    <?php
    $i = 0;
    foreach(array_diff(scandir($dir_handle), array('.', '..')) as $file) {
        echo 'img' . $i . ' = new Image();' . PHP_EOL;
        echo 'img' . $i . '.src = "' . $file . '";' . PHP_EOL;
        $i++;
    }
    ?>
}
</script>
```

Comment: Doesn't that mean that I'd have to put in a src for every image? Would  it be possible to do a `foreach()` to find the names of the images in the folder and replace the `.src` with their location?

Comment: @user3352340 you can use foreach, ofc to generate the JS.